# Use PC USB headset for Xbox One Game Chat

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10

I have a Wireless USB Headset (Logitech g930) I use for PC. I do not have a headset for Xbox One. I'd like to able to use game chat to communicate with team mates and such.

I am able to use party chat through the Xbox App... but that doesn't work very well on games with randoms, or communication with players not in my party.

I wasn't able to find anything within the app, but seeing as it can do party chat.. I'd imagine game chat should be doable as well, right?

It doesn't seem like plugging the USB Receiver into the Xbox works, either... Plus, I'd still like to keep PC Audio for other things (music, discord, etc).

Is there a way to use a PC mic on Xbox One Game Chat outside of Party?